# Good libraries for working with probabilistic graphical models?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, references, graphical-model, software

Could someone recommend some well-maintained and up-to-date libraries for working with probabilistic graphical models?

I noticed that there are some libraries for R listed [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html) and [one for C++](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~jmooij1/libDAI/), but are there some other good libraries in C++ or Python?

Comment: I don't work with PGM but `PyMC` & `libpgm` come to mind considering Python. I haven't heard anything big and specific regarding C++. And then there is the Microsoft road with `Infer.NET`, that just based on the people working on it should be straight-up awesome...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking software / packages.

Answer (score 3):

A relatively new (and rapidly evolving) python library is pgmpy [(Github Link)](https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy).

Comment: Can you tell us anything about this library?